# Resize view group without having its children resized

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am trying to achieve a collapse animation. The view gets resized as expected, but i'd like its children not resized. See the follwing drawing for a clearer explanation:

[image: schema]

My children views have their height set to `wrap_content`, I know that the behavior of `wrap_content` is to fit the content size unless its bigger than the parent. So how can I achieve what I want (appart from setting a hard coded height value of X dp)?

Btw, this is basically the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856302/android-layout-resizing-parent-without-resizing-the-childs) except the given solution only apply to `TextView` children, which is not my case.

Comment: Try by giving the height of the child views fixed values rather than wrap_content

Comment: That's a solution, but that's also exactly what I want to avoid (like I said by saying that I don't want hard coded height values). But thanks though

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have same problem.